# javafx application not running in virtual mac os

Tags: macos, javafx, virtual-machine

**operating system :- OS X Mavericks**

**platform :- vmware workstation**

**java version: jdk1.8**

These are the softwares I am using to run the mac os x in a virtual machine. The problem is javafx application doesn't execute. Please help me how to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Whats does the stack trace say?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting while trying to execute the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is not [certified](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) "VMware is not a certified hypervisor" - i.e. it is not guaranteed to work with JavaFX and is unsupported.  I have no advice on how you might get it to work.

Comment: I know this could be the reason. But I dont know why javafx is not supported. It is not a high end application. And I havent didn't do hardware virtualization bypasser so could this be the reason. I dont know what a hardware virtualization bypasser does

Comment: thank you for you answer. I haven't done the hardware virtualization bypasser for vmware so I guess this is the problem. I will provide an answer when my problem will be solved